# How to disconnect Eclipse from internet?

Tags: xml, eclipse

Everytime I copy an XML file in my project, Eclipse would start to validate the XML file that contains some links. It takes a lot of time in validating and I want to tell eclipse "please dont validate if I dont ask you to validate."

What option should check/uncheck in eclipse? Any workaround?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
Window | Preferences | XML | XML Files | Validation | Enable markup validation (checkbox)
```